# Various shells won't run a binary that exists

Tags: executable, glibc, dynamic-linking

I downloaded several pre-built binaries of the same program  ([nodejs-linux, -x86, -x86_64](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v7.x/)). In different shells I get a similar error that `no such file or directory: node`. The `$PATH` is correct and the binaries exist and are executable.

Is this because I'm on a `musl`-based linux distribution and the binaries use `glibc`?  I thought the programs would crash or exit non-zero in such a case.

Note: Both @DepressionDaniel and @xhienne gave correct answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your libairies dont match the dynamic librairies required by the executable, it won't even start. To check the dynamic librairies this executable is linked to, do:

```
ldd /path/to/executable
```

If you see `=> not found`, you know what is missing.

Comment: Thanks. For others interested: Here is a similar situation with `ldd` on a `musl` OS in action: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33240548/841803

Answer (score 2):

You error is caused not by a missing shared object, but by not having the *dynamic loader* used by the application.

If the dynamic loader can't be found, `exec()` gives back `ENOENT` to the shell, which translates to the error message you get.

If a dynamic loader is found, `exec()` succeeds, and the dynamic loader has a chance to print an informative message about a missing shared object if such should be the case.

This can be tried out easily, by knobbling a binary like `ls` in different ways:

```
cd /tmp
cp $(which ls) .
sed -e 's/libc.so.6/BAD!.so.6/' <ls >ls2
sed -e 's/ld-linux/ha-hahah/' <ls >ls3
strace ./ls2
strace ./ls3
```

So, I would say your `musl`-based Linux is so radical, that not only does it change `glibc` for something else, it also places the dynamic loader on an unconventional path, or gives it an unconventional name.

Comment: You're right. It's `/lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1` on this machine, but the binary uses `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.